# Change LC_CTYPE for PostgreSQL and PostGIS use

Tags: postgresql, locale, postgis, geodjango

So I'm walking through the GeoDjango tutorial and I'm stuck on this error message:

```
postgres@lucid32:~$ createdb -E UTF8 template_postgis
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  encoding UTF8 does not match locale en_US
DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding LATIN1.
```

I've googled and read some Ubuntu docs but to no avail. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using the default Vagrant Box lucid 32, for testing out my setup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is better to just specify the locale for the database and have the encoding be figured out from that.  So use something like

```sh
createdb --locale=en_US.utf8 template_postgis
```

Comment: What I actually ended up doing is createdb -E UTF8 -T template0 --locale=en_US.utf8 template_postgis

Comment: `--locale=en_US.UTF-8` as of PostgreSQL 9.4.5

Answer (score 9):

Both  -E UTF8 and --locale=en_US.utf8 are needed

```
$ createdb -E UTF8 -T template0 --locale=en_US.utf8 template_postgis
```

Answer (score 5):

Else, try this when you log in to postgresql :

```
create database databse_name with owner database_owner encoding='UTF-8'lc_collate='en_US.utf8' lc_ctype='en_US.utf8' template template0;
```

Comment: plus 1 for adding template0

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your operating system's locale to any utf8 compatible locale.  Run `locale -a` to get a list of locales you can use, and then do something like `update-locale LANG=en_US.utf8`, replacing en_US.utf8 with whatever locale you want.

Answer (score 2):

look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20880/unicode-in-postgresql-8-4/114922#114922

maybe you need configure the locale before to create the cluster

```
~#export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
~#export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
~#export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
~#locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
~#dpkg-reconfigure locales
```